# Using bash comm command on columns but returning the entire line

Tags: bash, sorting, command, comm

I have two files, each with two columns and sorted only by the second column, such as:

```
File 1: 

176 AAATC
6   CCGTG
80  TTTCG

File 2:

20 AAATC
77 CTTTT
50 TTTTT
```

I would like to use comm command using options -13 and -23 to get two different files reporting the different lines between the two files with the corresponding count number, but only comparing the second columns (i.e. the strings). What I tried so far was something like:

```
comm -23 <(cut -d$'\t' -f2 file1.txt) <(cut -d$'\t' -f2 file2.txt)
```

But I could only have the strings in output, without the numbers:

```
 CCGTG
 TTTCG
```

While what I want would be:

```
 6  CCGTG
 80 TTTCG
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: you've stated you want 2 output files; please update the question to show the contents of 2 output files; can the value in the 2nd column show up more than once in either of the input files?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join` instead of `comm`:

```
join -1 2 -2 2 File1 File2 -a 1 -o 1.1,1.2,2.2
```

It will output the matching lines, too, but you can remove them with

```
| grep -v '[ACTG] [ACTG]'
```

Explanation:

- `-1 2` use the second column in file 1 for joining;
- `-2 2` similarly, use the second column in file 2;
- `-a 1` show also non-matching lines from file 1 - these are the ones you want in the end;
- `-o` specifies the output format, here we want columns 1 and 2 from file 1 and column 2 from file 2 (this is just arbitrary, you can use column 1 as well, but the second command would be different: `| grep -v '[ACTG] [0-9]'`).

Answer (score 0):

`comm` is not the right tool for this job, and while `join` will work you also need to look at running `join` twice and then further filter the results with some other command (eg, `grep`).

One `awk` idea that requires a single pass through each input file:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"}

FNR==NR  { f1[$2]=$1; next }           # save 1st file entries

$2 in f1 { delete f1[$2]; next }       # 2nd file: if $2 in f1[] then delete f1[] entry and skip this line else ..
         { f2[$2]=$1 }                 # save 2nd file entries

END      { # at this point:
           # f1[] contains rows where field #2 only exists in the 1st file
           # f2[] contains rows where field #2 only exists in the 2nd file

           PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_str_asc"
           for (i in f1) print f1[i],i > "file-23"
           for (i in f2) print f2[i],i > "file-13"
         }
' file1 file2
```

**NOTE:** the `PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` line requires `GNU awk`; without this line we cannot guarantee the order of writes to the final output files, and OP would then need to add more (`awk`) code to maintain the ordering or use another OS-level utility (eg, `sort`) to sort the final files

This generates:

```
$ cat file-23
6       CCGTG
80      TTTCG

$ cat file-13
77      CTTTT
50      TTTTT
```